# How do i get the amount of tokens received for a swap on Uniswap/Pancakeswap so i can exchange them back later

Tags: solidity, nodejs, uniswap, pancakeswap

I have successfully used the swapExactTokensForTokens() and approve() functions on Pancakeswap with ethers js.

Uniswap docs say that swapExactTokensForTokens() returns The input token amount and all subsequent output token amounts.

Im assuming its in the .data field of the transaction receipt but have no idea how to get a readable value?

```
  nonce: 487,
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x012a05f200', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01d10d', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  data: '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',
  chainId: 56,
  v: 148,
  r: '0xb1b1819bf6298997e5ed3b751d5b722080cc6b1d5913e90e3a48893d4b556977',
  s: '0x236716287249d6ead409084626ad0942e32092854d491c68545c0959a84045d0',
  from: '0xe74c007541f7FEE39aD098b2C4a7C21128E13AC1',
  hash: '0x8edb0c46645522380aa50eab2cd79ef5165ad667ffd2b427b8e1f3b88a592aa3',
  type: null,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```